# Tricentis Tosca - ListBox

Tags: automation, automated-tests, tosca, uat

Current I am having the Automation Specialist Level 1 course, and I would like to seek for advice for the following issue. Thanks.

In the practice exercise, I have to scan the Menu items on the Black Menu bar like "Books" and " Computers" with Tosca DEMO site ([http://demowebshop.tricentis.com/login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvNXJ.jpg)). The tutorial video demonstrates the control items(refer to image 1), but for me, I cannot locate those items either by the "scan on screen" method or by selecting the available control items(refer to image 2), to me only a listbox is available.

With the trouble advice, the issue seems relate to Resolution issue, but indeed I have set both displays of my browser and my monitor to 100% but it does not help resolve the issue.

Any advise is highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvNXJ.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIYYq.jpg)

Comment: Please provide some code you have been working on :) also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Good day @Y-B Cause, thank you for the warm welcome. For the issue I posted, I think I have found a workaround for that. Currently, if I use the Internet Explorer as browser, the xScan function in TOSCA only allow the scanning in either "UIA" or "onlyUI" mode, then I switch the browser to Chrome, and "html" mode appears in xScan, the issue is then resolved as those "li" html elements like "books" or "computers" are available for scanning again. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you have managed to solve this by now?